# Add Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 to InstallShield

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, installshield

### Issue

---

I have just set up my *InstallSheild* which works fine and i am just wondering how i can add the *(x86) + (x64)* version of this download : https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145 to my InstallShield so the user has to install it.

I have tried to get this working on One-Click but this also does not work.

Has anyone tried adding this package to there InstallShield?

Comment: I just download it and execute the .exe downloaded file

Comment: @FirstStep I want the download to be in with the Install of my application though? I can't email the user and say "download this" every time?

Comment: Use the merge modules.  You already have them on your machine, stored in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Merge Modules directory.

Answer (score 0):

If its simple MSI project then you go into Application data/Redistributables search for desired package to add, probably needs to be downloaded first. When you check it it should be included and installed before feature selection, you can change this option in this view. (i dont have personal experience with this)

But i have suite project which includes c++ redist 2015. You can add it in Packages view, right click it and add new executable. You can map it from the installshield folder (where it was downloaded from the step i wrote above) or from the place you have downloaded it before.

Comment: actualy when u right click it u should add it as prq, since it will set the detections of previous versions

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a prerequisite for Visual C++ Redistributable. In that prerequisite, you just need to mention a path of exe (files to include). You can set this path to the download location where you have already downloaded that exe.
So it will get added to your installer. And then while installation it'll get installed on target system on one click.